# Are AWOS data open for commercial use?

Tags: weather, datasets

I 've found out this great [website](https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/request/download.phtml?network=ID__ASOS) where you can get historical AWOS weather data. I would like to use it for a commercial application but I don't find any data license. Do you know if the AWOS data are free to use for commercial purposes? Can you point me to a relevant link?

Comment: A bunch of random folks on the internet aren't going to know that. I'd recommend that you contact the fine folks at Iowa State and ask them.

Answer (score 1):

Your website source from Iowa State University may or may not be open for commercial use. As Freeman has said in his comment, it would be difficult for anyone here on the internet not affiliated with the university to know. Your best opportunity to use their data is to contact the university directly. Their contact information is at the bottom of the link you provided.

Otherwise, your best option is to contact NOAA, the NCEP or the National Weather Service (basically, one and the same organization). They collect, consolidate, and archive the data at their source. That is where many commercial applications get their data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Really helpful. I was maybe thinking that it was commonly known in the aviation community if this data source is open or not, hence my question. Your suggestions and the one from FreeMan are very good, I will directly contact the organizations that you mentioned... and post the answer here once I get a reply :)

Comment: @greghor - No problem. Unless Iowa State has done something to add a unique value added proposition to their data in order to make the user interface easier for commercial use, it might be better to go directly to the source of the information. After all Iowa State is getting their data (probably for free) from the NCEI, a division of NOAA. More than likely, so can you. Good luck.

Comment: +1 on Dean’s last comment.  This data is produced using taxpayer dollars, and is broadcast for public consumption.  You are wise to ask these questions, especially if another entity has gone to the trouble to collect and archive it, and especially if you intend to use it commercially, but you ought to be able to find a way to gather and use what is in the public domain.

Comment: The question has been closed but let me write here the answer I got from NOAA. In the general case, AWOS data can NOT be used for commercial purpose